# Disable PyYAML value conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have just started to use **PyYAML** to convert some data.

I just use the `yaml.load` function and it was good enough for me until I noticed that it tries to convert all values to uni-coded string, int, dates and so on.

This could be fatal in my application, is there a way to avoid this conversion?
I would like to receive everything as strings.
I looked at the constructors and could not find a way to disable this conversion.

update:
What I get from `yaml.load` is an `OrderedDict` and everything looks good. the only problem is that some values are string, and some are int. I would like to have all values as strings. I don´t want pyyaml to convert the values for me.

Comment: Then you're not decoding YAML. Besides, **what exactly** do you want to leave as strings and what not? If you leave *everything* a string, you want `the_file.read()` ;-)

Comment: The file I am using pyyaml to parse is actually not yaml but it is close enough. Therefore I want to avoid type-conversion.

Comment: But *what* kind of type conversion? Do you want to receive lists? Dictionaries? Do you want booleans to be converted? Floats? To arbitrary depth or with a fixed format? As it stands, this is way too under-specified.

Comment: @delnan, please see the updated information

Comment: As an example for wanting this, suppose you have a data structure where a two-letter location code has historically been put into YAML unquoted, and you would like the location code `on` to *not* be converted to `True`.

Comment: Do you only want the values (i.e. the scalars that are values in a mapping) or do you also want keys, or  sequence elements that are scalars that get converted to be kept as strings.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, you could use `Loader=yaml.BaseLoader` to leave everything as a string:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3], {1:2}]
>>> s = yaml.dump(x)
>>> s
'- [1, 2, 3]\n- {1: 2}\n'
>>> yaml.load(s)
[[1, 2, 3], {1: 2}]
>>> yaml.load(s, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
[[u'1', u'2', u'3'], {u'1': u'2'}]
```

Comment: Beware: while this does disable automatic value conversion, it also appears to cause the "<<" merge key to no longer work across more than a single level (i.e. "<<"-merging an anchor node that itself also "<<"-merges other anchor nodes will no longer work) -- tested on PyYAML 3.10 and 3.11

Comment: This also causes the keys and (sequence) elements to be constructed as strings, not just the scalar values in a YAML document.